# How to get object's reference in the server?

Tags: c#, .net, singleton, client-server, remoting

When registering an object in the server by

```
RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(Interfaces.client), Singleton", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton); //in the server
```

then retrieving it in the client by

```
Interfaces.client mgr = (Interfaces.client)(Activator.GetObject(typeof(Interfaces.client), "tcp://localhost:1234/Singleton")); //in the client
```

so that the object can be accessed from the client and we can see modifications in the server side, this is already done.
My specific problem is: where can I find object's reference in server after it's created?
(in singleton or singlecall mode), I know there would be several instances, if it's singlecall mode, even though, I assume that instances are stored by some Naming service macanism, or directly in some list in memory.
please forgive my weak English

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create the object separately then marshal it instead of using RegisterWellKnownServiceType:

`Foo foo = new Foo();`

`RemotingServices.Marshal(foo, "Singleton");`

So client changes will be reflected on the server side in the foo object.

Comment: This way, it's impossible to register object in singlecall mode (one instance for each call)

Comment: @initParam That's correct it applies to singletons only. Single call instances should live for as short a time as possible. If you need access to a single call instance server side then your design is wrong.